# Recuperar variable extraída de un JSON en Android

Tags: json, youtube-api

Me ha surgido un problema, tengo que sacar los datos de un archivo JSON, el idVideo lo almaceno con un setter de la clase Video para después en otro método poder acceder al dato con un getter, que es como se haría normalmente, pero el valor siempre es null

Adjunto el código de la extracción de datos del json:

```
public void sacarJsonInfoVideo(String url){

    RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString(0));

                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    String idVideo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("id").getString("videoId");
                    video.setIdVideo(idVideo);

                    String tituloVideo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                    video.setTitulo(tituloVideo);

                    String fechaSubida=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("publishedAt");
                    String SfechaSubida=fechaSubida.substring(0, 10);
                    video.setDiaSubida(SfechaSubida);

                    String nombreCanal=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("channelTitle");
                    video.setNombreCanal(nombreCanal);

                    String miniatura=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("default").getString("url");
                    video.setMiniatura(miniatura);


                    listVideo.add(video);
                }

                String idVideos =listVideo.get(0).getIdVideo();
                System.out.println("Id a reproducir(sacarJsonInfoVideo): "+ idVideos);

                tvNombreVideo.setText(listVideo.get(0).getTitulo());
                tvNombreCanal.setText(listVideo.get(0).getNombreCanal());
                tvFechaSubida.setText(listVideo.get(0).getDiaSubida());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                siguienteVideo(v);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Holi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Método para acceder con un getter, obtenerRandomIdVideo() es un método para obtener 5 caracteres aleatorios para hacer una búsqueda. El getter lo almaceno en la variable sdw, devuelve nulo :(

```
public void siguienteVideo(View v){

    String idVideo=obtenerRandomIdVideo();
    System.out.println("Id URL(siguienteVideo): "+idVideo);

    String urlBuscarVideo="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=5&type=video&q="+idVideo+"&key="+claveYT;

    sacarJsonInfoVideo(urlBuscarVideo);

    String sdw=video.getIdVideo();

    System.out.println("Video que se va a reproducir YA: "+sdw);
}
```

Sólo pasa esto cuando intento recuperar variables desde un json, es algo normal en los métodos json ?

**EDIT:**

Lo he comprobado varias veces y es como si se ejecutara antes el video.getIdVideo() que el método sacarJsonInfoVideo(String url) que asigna un valor a video.getIdVideo().

Eso es lo que sale por consola de debug.

```
I/System.out: String a buscar(obtenerRandomIdVideo): 5mey1
          Id URL(siguienteVideo): 5mey1
I/System.out: Video que se va a reproducir YA: null
I/System.out: Id a reproducir(sacarJsonInfoVideo): 3FTkUWUc7es
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del método sacarJsonInfoVideo estás llamando a JsonObjectRequest que es una petición asíncrona, por lo que cuando llamas a sacarJsonInfoVideo la respuesta no la vas a tener inmediatamente sino cuando llegue al método onResponse. Así pues, este código debería ir dentro del onResponse:

```
String sdw=video.getIdVideo();
System.out.println("Video que se va a reproducir YA: "+sdw);
```

Es desde este método desde donde llamas al método que te interese pasándole el valor obtenido

Comment: Vale funciona, pero yo lo que quiero es usar la variable sdw en otro método, porque al llamarla desde fuera sigue siendo una petición asíncrona

Comment: El tema es que no puedes usar el valor hasta que no lo obtienes y, como es una petición asíncrona, solo lo puedes emplear en la respuesta de la petición (onResponse). En ese momento depende de lo que quieras hacer pues necesitas un código u otro. Por ejemplo, si quieres mostrar el valor en un campo en pantalla, pues tendrás que actualizar el control dentro de una llamada a runOnUiThread

Comment: Gracias! Ya lo he conseguido :)))

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! Encantado de poder ayudar