# Problema al acceder a una variable creada en el JSONObjectRequest fuera de él en Android

Tags: android, json

Tengo un método con el que saco información de un JSON, las variables las guardo con un setter de la clase Video, para después en otro método acceder al valor de esa variable con un getter. El problema es que siempre es nulo

Código del método de extracción de datos de JSON:

```
public void sacarJsonInfoVideo(String url){

    RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString(0));

                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    String idVideo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("id").getString("videoId");
                    video.setIdVideo(idVideo);

                    String tituloVideo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                    video.setTitulo(tituloVideo);

                    String fechaSubida=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("publishedAt");
                    String SfechaSubida=fechaSubida.substring(0, 10);
                    video.setDiaSubida(SfechaSubida);

                    String nombreCanal=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("channelTitle");
                    video.setNombreCanal(nombreCanal);

                    String miniatura=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("default").getString("url");
                    video.setMiniatura(miniatura);


                    listVideo.add(video);
                }

                String idVideos = listVideo.get(0).getIdVideo();
                System.out.println("Id a reproducir(sacarJsonInfoVideo): "+ idVideos);

                tvNombreVideo.setText(listVideo.get(0).getTitulo());
                tvNombreCanal.setText(listVideo.get(0).getNombreCanal());
                tvFechaSubida.setText(listVideo.get(0).getDiaSubida());

                idVideoFinal=video.getIdVideo();
                System.out.println("Video que se va a reproducir YA(final): "+idVideoFinal);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                siguienteVideo(v);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Holi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Código del método en el que quiero usar el getter que es un botón:

```
public void siguienteVideo(View v){

    String idVideo=obtenerRandomIdVideo();
    System.out.println("Id URL(siguienteVideo): "+idVideo);

    String urlBuscarVideo="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=5&type=video&q="+idVideo+"&key="+claveYT;

    sacarJsonInfoVideo(urlBuscarVideo);

    String getter=video.getIdVideo();

    System.out.println("Video que se va a reproducir YA(siguienteVideo): "+getter);
}
```

En el primer método guardo todas las variables con un setter y en el segundo quiero acceder con un getter. El problema es que la llamada a JSONObjectRequest es asíncrona, con lo cual realiza antes el getter que el setter.

He visto que lo que se puede hacer es poner el código en el onResponse, pero yo lo que quiero es acceder a la variable desde el segundo método para hacer una llamada a otro método.

Comment: En lugar de hacer setters, llena el objeto. Creando el constructor con las variables que quieras usar del objeto "Video" en este caso.

Comment: Y luego como puedo acceder en otro método al objeto que acabo de llenar ?

Comment: Duplicado ? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191125/recuperar-variable-extraída-de-un-json-en-android

Answer (score 0):

Eso es fácil, instanciando la clase. Si lo declaras fuera de los métodos te vale para todos los métodos que tengas en la clase.

ejemplo:

Video nombre;

public void metodoTalDeCual(){

nombre.getMetodoObjeto();

}

De la misma forma para un ArrayList, solo que tienes que recorrerlo y cuando estés en la posición que desees sacas el objeto de 'i'